# Stop on click and restart to 0

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

```
    <StackPanel>
        <MediaElement x:Name="UnMediaElement"
         Height="10"
         Width="10"
         Source="/Assets/sounds/unu.wav"
         AutoPlay="False" />

        <Button x:Name="play1SoundButton"
                Height="80"
                Width="200"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Content="Play Sound"
                Click="play1SoundButton_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

I have 2 buttons. When I press button1, it will play a sound. I want the sound to stop and restart to 0 when I press button2. Right now, if I press on button1 and then on 2 and then again on button1, it resumes. Also, I don't want to be able to play another sound while one is playing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your player just doesn't stop the looping audio instead it pauses it. If you are using an Audio Control that has "controlName.pause();" look for "controlname.Stop();". This will stop the whole audio loop and then will start from the beginning when you click your "Play Sound" Again.

2) On your Audio Control, There will be a flag method which will return you if your Control is In Use (Playing Something). If Yes, You can stop it and play next audio.

Few simple things before you go back to your code after reading this.

It would be lot better if you post some code and show where you are having problem. I cannot help but give you theoretical answers only since there is no info as to what your methods are doing exactly.

Edit: Based on the Code that you posted, Change your method to below. Then you should be able to play seamless media.

```
private void play1SoundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DoiMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
    {
         DoiMediaElement.Stop();
    }
    UnMediaElement.Play();
}
private void play2SoundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (UnMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
     {
         UnMediaElement.Stop();
     }
     DoiMediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Here's the code. (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express,developing a soundboard app for Windows Phone 8.0,newbie here!)

http://i.imgur.com/bCHz3ne.png

Comment: This is the mainpage.xaml.cs code,I've got no such thing as pause or stop.    private void play1SoundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnMediaElement.Play();
        }

        private void play2SoundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoiMediaElement.Play();

Comment: I Just edited my answer and posted a snippet based on the methods that you are using. Try using this.

Also Below Link should help you big time. There are lot of other things that you can do with MediaElement. Check it out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242926

Comment: Error 1 The name 'MediaElementState' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Zaraf\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PhoneApp2\PhoneApp2\MainPage.xaml.cs 27 49 PhoneApp2